# Laravel and Magniloquent, validate two models together

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models, `users` and `schools`.

The scenario is that I save user first into users table then get the `user id` and insert it into `schools` table together with other details.

My problem is how can I validate both of these models using Magniloquent, given that the creation view contains both user and school input fields?

i.e. Whenever I create a `user` I have to create a `school` and vise versa. I really want to use Magniloquent but if someone has other ideas, they are welcome.

*NOTE: I am comfortable with validating individual models.*

Comment: Can you share some details on specifically what isn't working in your implementation?  Like some code examples, or a better explanation of what it does now that isn't what you want?  It's hard to understand what your business logic looks like from your explanation, so even harder to suggest possible solutions.

Comment: Without knowing more, I would say both your User and School models need to extend the validate() method so you can add some custom code in there to make them aware of each other at creation.   Maybe your base model needs some kind of transaction-like static method that creates and validates a series of models together but only saves them if they all pass validation together?